# static OnceLock gets seemingly erroneous "is never used" warning

Tags: rust, static, compiler-warnings

I have this in lib.rs:

```
static REQWEST_CLIENT: OnceLock<Client> = OnceLock::new();

pub fn get_reqwest_client() -> &'static Client {
    REQWEST_CLIENT.get_or_init(|| {
        let es_path = r#"D:\apps\ElasticSearch\elasticsearch-8.6.2\config"#;
        set_var("ES_PATH_CONF", &es_path); // from crate tmp_env
        let mut buf = Vec::new();
        let cert_path = format!(r#"{es_path}\certs\http_ca.crt"#);
        let mut cert_file = File::open(cert_path).expect("problem opening certificate file");
        cert_file.read_to_end(&mut buf).ok();
        let cert = reqwest::Certificate::from_pem(&buf).expect("problem generating certificate"); // delivers cert OK
    
        Client::builder()
            .add_root_certificate(cert)
            .timeout(std::time::Duration::from_millis(5_000))
            .build()
            .expect("problem building the reqwest client")
    })
}
```

... it is indeed used: when the first line above is commented out, not surprisingly it all fails.

I've searched on this and it doesn't generally seem to be accepted that the compiler gets things wrong on this subject: usually in such questions it turns out there's an error like someone has declared something to be `pub` but not used it outside the crate.

So I'm surprised that the compiler should be making such a "mistake". Is there a way to suppress this one warning without affecting anything else? FWIW I tried putting `#[allow(dead_code)]` in the line above this line: this had no effect.

**Possible explanation**
Just realised what the possible explanation *might* be. The only time the above function is called is inside a macro. [duang](https://crates.io/crates/duang/0.1.2) is a way of implementing default and/or named parameters in Rust.

```
duang!(
    pub fn reqwest_call(url: &str, method: reqwest::Method = reqwest::Method::GET, timeout: usize = 5, 
        required_dict: HashMap<String, Value> = HashMap::new(), acceptable_status_codes: Vec<u16> = vec![200]) 
        -> Result<reqwest::blocking::Response, Box<dyn Error>> {
        let response_result = get_reqwest_client()
        .request(method, url)
        .header("Content-type", "application/json")
        .basic_auth("mike12", Some("mike12"))
        .send(); 
        ...
```

Assuming this is the explanation, any way to suppress it?

**I tried this:**

```
#[allow(dead_code)]        
fn do_nothing(){
    info!("{:#?}", REQWEST_CLIENT.get());
}
```

... and even put `do_nothing()` in a couple of places. Still getting the warning.

Comment: Are you getting an unused code warning from `get_reqwest_client` as well? Or only for `REQWEST_CLIENT`?

Comment: What version of Rust are you compiling with?

Comment: That's the only warning I'm getting during compile. Version is 1.70.0.

Comment: Any warning can be supressed with `#allow(name_of_the warning)`. Did you try that?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce even with duang added, though if this is already at the top level the `pub` on `get_reqwest_client` means it shouldn't affect its accessibility anyway. Are you getting the warning from `cargo check/build`? Or from your IDE?

Comment: @rodrigo But won't that suppress every instance of the warning? I just want this one spurious warning to be suppressed.

Comment: This problem will be very difficult to diagnose without an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @kmdreko The only compile command I'm using is `maturin develop --release`. But I just tried `cargo check` and it gives this warning on my system.

Comment: Weird... If you do a `cargo clean` and re-check does the warning persist?

Comment: Just tried that: no change, still getting it. Could it be an unfortunate combination of other crates? Could it be because this is on W10, not *nix? Re MRE: I'm a Rust newb but must work out that stuff. I'll have to strip everything down and then build up again. Could take some time...

Comment: _But won't that suppress every instance of the warning?_ That is if you write `#![allow(...)]` at the beginning of the module. If you write `#[allow(...)]` without the `!` before the variable then it will suppress just that particular instance. Check this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4329acf6170768dc6bd1b3e5a32055ca).

Comment: @rodrigo Ah, OK. But I mentioned in the question that I already tried `#[allow(dead_code)]` before that line. I've just tried `#[allow(is_never_used)]` and `#[allow(never_used)]`: both got an "unknown lint" warning. Do you have another lint directive in mind that I should try?

Comment: I think you had put the directive before the function, not before the variable. Did you try both? The last resort would be to write all your related code into a private module, and put the `#![allow(...)]` inside that module, then `use` whatever you need from the parent module. BTW, the particular name of the warning can be copied from the warning messabe, except that there it is shown as `note: #[warn(dead_code)]` on by default` or something.

Comment: Ah, yes that is indeed the note (and yes, "dead code"). I just put `#[allow(dead_code)]` before the function: no change. I'm going to have to strip things down and build up again to experiment. This crate is a utility crate, and `reqwest_call` is being called from another crate (hence `pub`).